# Python Programming Knapsack List index error

Tags: python, list, indexing, knapsack-problem, greedy

I'm working on a simple greedy knapsack problem.  My code is functional but is dependent on certain elements in a list being in the correct order; more specifically when an element is the highest value in our list AND positioned towards the start of our list, that element is appended to a final returned list, and then removed from the initial list - the problem I am facing is the natural movement of elements and their indices impacting the next iteration

Below is my code with an example call

```
def expensive_thief(weights, values, capacity):
    returned_knapsack = []
    weight_count = 0

    value_list = list(values)
    weight_list = list(weights)

    while weight_count < capacity:
        best_value = max(values)
        i = values.index(best_value)
        if weights[i] <= capacity - weight_count:
            returned_knapsack.append(i)
            weight_count = weight_count + weights[i]
        del values[i]
        del weights [i]

    return returned_knapsack
```

```
print(expensive_thief([4,9,1,5,1], [5,10,9,8,4], 10))
```

should return and print `[1,2]` as these are the indices of the items with the highest values which also make a max capacity

with my code, the initial highest valued element (element 1 with weight 9 and value 10 is added to a final list and removed, removing this element however shifts the index of every other element, the next element to be added (which is the correct element or originally element at index 2) is otherwise referenced at index 1)

I understand indexing and referencing but cant seem to wrap my head around a solution. please help!

Comment: It's probably best not to actually _remove_ the items, but instead come up with some way of simply _ignoring_ the items you've already chosen.

Comment: Besides John's suggestion, there are couple problems with the algorithm itself. For a greedy algorithm, which seems to be attempted here, items should be arranged by relative value (ie value per unit weight), not the absolute value. However, you should be aware greedy algorithm isn't guaranteed to find the optimal solution; for this, you'll need something more sophisticated like branch and bound or dynamic programming.